Draw PDF with a different colour in a CALayer. (Objective-C)
I've loaded a black and transparent .PDF icon to a CGPDFPageRef and need to draw it out to a CALayer with a specified colour. I can scale and rotate it correctly but don't know how to change the colour it's rendered in.
This is part of a macOS desktop application that maps aircraft in flight. I have been using an NSImage to draw .PNG aircraft icons but as my source icons are 128x128 they often appear slightly blurry when an NSImage is scaled down to 40x40. I have been converting the icons to 128x128 Vector PDF files and the code below draws them correctly scaled and orientated on a CALayer but I don’t seem to be able to change the colour they are drawn in.
When I used NSImages to load .png’s I have some code to read the .png to an NSImage then create a new NSImage with the changed colour and I suspect I’ll need to do the same with a PDF but have no idea how to do that.
My code to render the .PDF icon to the map is:
// Render a PDF vector icon
- (void)drawAircraftInContext:(CGContextRef)context acft:(Aircraft *)acft
{
   CGContextSaveGState (context);

   CGRect pdfRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect (acft.pdf, kCGPDFCropBox);

   CGContextTranslateCTM (context, acft.x, acft.y);
   CGContextRotateCTM (context, degreesToRadians (acft.heading));
   CGContextTranslateCTM (context, (_iconSize / 2), (_iconSize / 2));
   CGContextScaleCTM (context, .0 - (_iconSize / pdfRect.size.width), .0 - (_iconSize / pdfRect.size.height));

// None of this block actually works - the colour remains black with a clear background.
   CGContextSetAlpha (context, _radarView.militaryAlpha);
   CGContextSetFillColorWithColor (context, _militaryColour);
   CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor (context, _militaryColour);
   CGContextSetBlendMode (context, kCGBlendModeMultiply);
// How do we change the colour of the image?

   CGContextDrawPDFPage (context, acft.pdf);

   CGRect rect = CGRectMake (0.0 - (_iconSize / 2.0), 0.0 - (_iconSize / 2.0), _iconSize, _iconSize);

   // Draw a highlight
   if (acft == _radarView.selected && !_radarView.showOnlySelectedAircraft)
      [self drawAircraftHighlightInContext:context rect:rect acft:acft];

   CGContextRestoreGState (context);
}

The code to load the PDF is:
  //Experimental to see if PDF images can be treated as vectors rather than images.
  if (acft.pdfIcon)
     {
     NSURL *nsurl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filename isDirectory:NO];
     CFURLRef url = (CFURLRef)CFBridgingRetain(nsurl);
     CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL (url);
     CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage (pdf, 1);

     /* Might need to create another CGPDFPageRef from the original and draw
        into it with the correct colour. */

     acft.pdf = page;
     }

Which then falls through to create an NSImage which I don’t need to do if I can change the colour:
  image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filename];

  /*
   * Our .png images are just black but we'll need to use the specified colour
   * to indicate military, civilian or simulator.
   */
  [image lockFocus];
  [[[NSColor colorWithCGColor:colour] colorWithAlphaComponent:alpha] set];
  NSRect imageRect = { NSZeroPoint, [image size] };
  NSRectFillUsingOperation (imageRect, NSCompositeSourceIn);
  [image unlockFocus];
  }

   if (image)
      {
      CGRect rect = CGRectMake (0.0, 0.0, _iconSize, _iconSize);

      return ([image CGImageForProposedRect:&rect
                                    context:nil
                                      hints:@{}]);
      }

  return ([image CGImageForProposedRect:&rect
                                context:nil
                                  hints:@{}]);
  }


How complex is your "Airplane Icon"? There may be a much simpler way to handle this...

Thank for you replaying @DonMag An example icon is at http://www.iridiumblue.com/pages/AW109.pdf It is a single page 128x128 in black on a clear background. I would like to change the colour of the black part to reflect military/civil/etc and apply an alpha if possible. I'm currently converting the icons to an NSImage which then losses quality whens called to say 40x40. Thanks.

This is what the App produces. http://www.iridiumblue.com/pages/Radar.png

You might be better off converting your Airplane "icons" to CGPath and then scaling / rotating the path for use as CAShapeLayer. As an example, I used that PDF to create a path -- various sizing: https://i.sstatic.net/AJUXwbL8.png -- and then 40x40 with rotation and positioning: https://i.sstatic.net/cwRNflYg.png ...

Can you use image views as subviews? If so, that's an option. If that won't work with what you're trying to do, if you post a [mre] I'm pretty sure I can modify your code to allow "coloring" the image.

Thanks @DonMag. A CGPath is much more useful to me than the image so if I could load the PDF to a CGPath that would be great.

It would help if you explained exactly what you need to do. Do you want to animate a CAShapeLayer? Do you want to draw the shape to the map bitmap? Do you just need to scale, rotate and color the image and place it on the map? It is possible to extract paths from a PDF file, but it can be finicky. For example, the AW109.pdf you linked to has some bad data in it, as seen here: https://i.sstatic.net/BOKtF0bz.png

Thanks @DonMag. If I can get the CGPath I can then hopefully scale the aircraft andchoose to just draw the outline or fill with colours to indicate military, police or civilian and various squark codes such as emergency or QRA. I usually draw CGPath's onto a CALayer with something like CGContextDrawPath (context, kCGPathStroke) or kCGPathFill. I'm not animating the aircraft just drawing them every 15 seconds. I think I can fix the errors in my .PDF by making them a single layer with a single path in. That helicopter was at least two layers as I thought I might animate the blades in the future.

A few notes...
First, as I mentioned in my comments, shapes / paths in PDF files can be finicky.
Using the original PDF you linked to - http://www.iridiumblue.com/pages/AW109.pdf :

And, using a PDF of an AC130 (can't remember where I got it):

You can edit the paths in the PDF file to fix problems... but, as you can see, fixing that AC130 might be a fair amount of work.
If it were me, I would generate my own CGMutablePath -- most PDF / vector editors can export the paths in various formats - such as SVG which can be converted fairly easily to CGPathMoveToPoint(...) / CGPathAddLineToPoint(...) / CGPathAddCurveToPoint(...) / etc.
If you're set on using PDF files and extracting the paths, here is some Example code...

Extractor.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <PDFKit/PDFKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface Extractor : NSObject
+ (NSArray<id> *)extractVectorPathsFromPDF:(NSURL *)pdfURL;
@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END


Extractor.m
#import "Extractor.h"

@implementation Extractor

void ExtractPathsFromContent(CGPDFScannerRef scanner, void *info);

void moveToCallback(CGPDFScannerRef scanner, void *info);
void lineToCallback(CGPDFScannerRef scanner, void *info);
void curveToCallback(CGPDFScannerRef scanner, void *info);
void closePathCallback(CGPDFScannerRef scanner, void *info);

CGMutablePathRef currentPath = NULL;

+ (NSArray<id> *)extractVectorPathsFromPDF:(NSURL *)pdfURL {
    PDFDocument *pdfDocument = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithURL:pdfURL];
    if (!pdfDocument) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to load PDF document.");
        return nil;
    }
    
    NSMutableArray<id> *vectorPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
    
    // Iterate through all pages in the PDF document
    for (NSInteger pageIndex = 0; pageIndex < pdfDocument.pageCount; pageIndex++) {
        PDFPage *pdfPage = [pdfDocument pageAtIndex:pageIndex];
        if (!pdfPage) continue;
        
        CGPDFPageRef cgPage = pdfPage.pageRef;
        if (!cgPage) continue;
        
        // Set up the scanner to process PDF content streams
        CGPDFContentStreamRef contentStream = CGPDFContentStreamCreateWithPage(cgPage);
        CGPDFOperatorTableRef operatorTable = CGPDFOperatorTableCreate();
        
        // Register custom callbacks for common operators for path extraction
        CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback(operatorTable, "m", &moveToCallback);  // move to
        CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback(operatorTable, "l", &lineToCallback);  // line to
        CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback(operatorTable, "c", &curveToCallback); // curve to
        CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback(operatorTable, "h", &closePathCallback); // close path
        
        CGPDFScannerRef scanner = CGPDFScannerCreate(contentStream, operatorTable, (__bridge void *)(vectorPaths));
        
        // Initialize a new path for the page
        currentPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
        
        // Scan the PDF content
        CGPDFScannerScan(scanner);
        
        // After scanning, add the current path to the paths array
        if (currentPath) {
            [vectorPaths addObject:(__bridge_transfer id)currentPath];
            currentPath = NULL;
        }
        
        // Clean up
        CGPDFScannerRelease(scanner);
        CGPDFContentStreamRelease(contentStream);
        CGPDFOperatorTableRelease(operatorTable);
    }
    
    return [vectorPaths copy];
}

// Callback for "move to" operator
void moveToCallback(CGPDFScannerRef scanner, void *info) {
    CGPDFReal x, y;
    if (CGPDFScannerPopNumber(scanner, &y) && CGPDFScannerPopNumber(scanner, &x)) {
        CGPathMoveToPoint(currentPath, NULL, x, y);
    }
}

// Callback for "line to" operator
void lineToCallback(CGPDFScannerRef scanner, void *info) {
    CGPDFReal x, y;
    if (CGPDFScannerPopNumber(scanner, &y) && CGPDFScannerPopNumber(scanner, &x)) {
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(currentPath, NULL, x, y);
    }
}

// Callback for "curve to" operator
void curveToCallback(CGPDFScannerRef scanner, void *info) {
    CGPDFReal x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3;
    if (CGPDFScannerPopNumber(scanner, &y3) && CGPDFScannerPopNumber(scanner, &x3) &&
        CGPDFScannerPopNumber(scanner, &y2) && CGPDFScannerPopNumber(scanner, &x2) &&
        CGPDFScannerPopNumber(scanner, &y1) && CGPDFScannerPopNumber(scanner, &x1)) {
        CGPathAddCurveToPoint(currentPath, NULL, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
    }
}

// Callback for "close path" operator
void closePathCallback(CGPDFScannerRef scanner, void *info) {
    CGPathCloseSubpath(currentPath);
}

@end


which can be used like this:
NSString *pdfName = @"AW109";
NSString *pdfPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:pdfName ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *pdfUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfPath isDirectory:NO];

// get the paths from the PDF
//  the PDF has only one page, so we're expecting only one path
NSArray<id> *vectorPaths = [Extractor extractVectorPathsFromPDF:pdfUrl];
CGPathRef pth = (CGPathRef)CFBridgingRetain([vectorPaths firstObject]);

// we now have a CGPathRef which can be drawn using CGContextDrawPath
//  or set as the .path of a CAShapeLayer


Another approach, which might be a better option -- use an NSImageView with the PDF file as an NSImage, and then scale / rotate / position that image view as a subview:
NSImageView *imgView = [NSImageView new];
imgView = [NSImageView new];
imgView.wantsLayer = YES;
imgView.imageScaling = NSImageScaleProportionallyUpOrDown;

// desired color
imgView.contentTintColor = NSColor.redColor;

NSString *pdfName = @"AW109";
NSString *pdfPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:pdfName ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *pdfUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfPath isDirectory:NO];

NSImage *img = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:pdfUrl];
img.template = YES;
imgView.image = img;

After some quick testing, Cocoa appears to do a nice job of processing the PDF file, and scales its paths when it is rendered.
For example - the original AW109.pdf, scaled to 3 sizes (image views are also each rotated 45º):


All the above images are placed on top of a "checker board pattern" so we can see the transparency.

@KJ - file won't download from that link. I posted an example project at: https://github.com/DonMag/PDFPathExtract ... you can clone the repo or download the PDF file only.

@KJ - yes, that AC130 is (likely) bigger and more detailed than needed. When I grabbed that, the OP had not indicated where he was getting the PDF file(s) from, nor whether he could edit them. I imagine it's also possible he would want to display a larger, detailed view of the icon. However, it is a good example of the difference between path extraction and loading the PDF as an NSImage.

@KJ - there are still some issues. I loaded your PDFs into my example app: https://i.sstatic.net/MtONnpBW.png ... notice that your AW109red still has the path glitch. Also, paths in PDFs can contain transforms (such as rotation) as seen in your airDoc3. As I said in my answer, if it were me I'd create my own CGPaths. If we're sticking with PDFs, I'd say using NSImage / NSImageView is much more reliable... although, that would not allow different stroke+fill colors.

@KJ - and, to be clear, I'm trying to offer the OP some help. This is not my task, and I don't know what constraints the OP has, nor do I know his full intents.

Thanks @DonMag. I'll try that code at the weekend. I assumed that PDF would be better supported for drawing, scaling and colouring vector icons. I'm creating my own icons in Affinity Designer 2 (350 to date) so could easily export as SVG if I knew how to extract a CGPath from an SVG. My own C-130 is at http://www.iridiumblue.com/pages/C130.pdf (256x256).

I've added http://www.iridiumblue.com/pages/C130.svg The SVG file looks readable and probably much easier extract a CGPath from than the PDF.

PocketSVG looks like it would do the job if I can't get the PDFs to work. https://github.com/pocketsvg/PocketSVG

@user9398585 - This is what I get with your C130.PDF: https://i.sstatic.net/itF7XF6j.png ... Now, it's very possible (likely) that my PDF path extractor is only suitable for simple paths and could be vastly improved. I still think using image views as subviews will be the most reliable and straightforward approach. If subviews won't work, I can also give you sample code to generate scaled + rotated + solid-color images which could be used as CALayer contents.

@user9398585 - you mention PocketSVG ... that library (as well as other SVG libs) typically processes an SVG file and creates a view with multiple shape layers.

Is PDFDocument available in macOS 12 Monterey? The documentation seems to suggest it does but I get:
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"OBJC_CLASS$_PDFDocument", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in PDFExtractor.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
But PDFDocument.h also has this:
PDFKIT_CLASS_AVAILABLE(10_4, 11_0)

I do have PDFKit.framework in my Frameworks

@user9398585 - you added the framework, but did you #import <PDFKit/PDFKit.h>?

Thanks @DonMag. The issue I think was that I had Deploy to 10.10 set when I added PDFKit. I removed it changed to macOS 12 then re-added and it worked. I do get some of the artefacts that you have previously shown. I'm not sure why but I may have to do some work on the icons and see if I need to simplify them. The C130.pdf has the engines as separate objects which may not help. I'll look at the NSImageView as well. Thank you very much for the time you spent on this. Your PDF Extractor is brilliant, Thanks.

I think I have some 'v' and 'y' type curves in my PDF which might cause an issue as I think they have different characteristics to a 'c' curve.

@user9398585 -- "'v' and 'y' type curves" -- I considered that. I added code to log any of those, but have not found a PDF that contain them. Some quick searching indicates it's unusual. There is a lot about PDF path/shape data that I am not familiar with. For example, if I create a PDF from either Sketch or InkScape... if I have a shape with both Fill and Border, my "extract path" code gets two paths, with the Border path inverted on the y-axis...

@user9398585 - the most reliable path extraction works when the PDF contains only closed, filled (but not bordered) paths. Since Cocoa appears to do a great job of rendering the PDF as an NSImage, clearly it's doing a lot of other work with the PDF data. If you can stick to filled paths, you should be OK. Otherwise, I'd use NSImage (unless you need different fill and stroke colors).
